# Unable to upload/download blob storage to container from local environment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, application-settings

I have an exiting functions app that has the functionality to download a file from sftp, process the file and upload file to blob storage. This functions app is already deployed in azure and working properly. However, when I run the same thing from visual studio (local) I get error at uploading file to blob storage.

Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

I made sure this app has the necessary contributor role assigned in a storage account (thats why its working from azure). Are there any other settings I need to configure in local settings or project settings for these functions to work same like when they are deployed to azure? Or could there be any settings in storage account that is overriding to perform upload operation when run from dev but run only from azure?

I made sure I use local settings have all are copied from app configuration which has storage account names, connection string of blob storage, sftp url, and key vault name which has credetails of sft site etc.,

**Update:**
Forgot to mention that az storage container upload command from command-line from my machine uploaded file successfully.

**update2:**
As per suggested by I have followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) and I was successfully able to create the container, upload blob and do cleanup without errors.
Then I consolidated code to simulate simple download blob into memory stream which is also throwing error

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
>   permission
>   (see full log in the bottom)

**Code to download blob:**

```
static async Task TokenCredentialsSample()
{
    var tenantId = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
    var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/",tenantId);
    var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(tokenProvider.Result);
    var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
    var uri = new Uri("https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/inbound/myfile.csv");

    var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri, storageCredentials);

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream); // Error here
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    memoryStream.Close();

}
```

I have also made sure I typed az login from command-line to switch to select correct subscription and also the account is selected in visual studio options.

**Error log:**

Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ExecuteSync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.RunWithoutSynchronizationContext[T](Func`1 actionToRun)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(Stream target, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(Stream target, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at BlobStorage.Program.d__2.MoveNext() in c:...\source\repos\BlobStorage\Program.cs:line 111
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at BlobStorage.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in c:...\source\repos\BlobStorage\Program.cs:line 19

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.RetryPolicies.IRetryPolicy, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.OperationContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync.AnonymousMethod__0()
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.RunWithoutSynchronizationContext(System.Func)
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.RetryPolicies.IRetryPolicy, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.OperationContext)
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(System.IO.Stream, long?, long?, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.AccessCondition, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.OperationContext)
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(System.IO.Stream, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.AccessCondition, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.OperationContext)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

Comment: Have you add you local IP address to the storage account firewall ?

Comment: your `external` ip address, not local IP address :)

Comment: @HuryShen Yes. I checked using what is my ip site and already added to it

Comment: So have you uploaded the file success after add your ip to it ? If still not success, could you please check if you use vpn and check if add the real ip address to your storage firewall ?

Comment: Maybe changing the CORS in your storage account will help?

Comment: can you post the function code?

Comment: @HuryShen I updated post. Forgot to mention that I was able to upload file using azure cli tool so I really doubt this is the issue, however to answer about VPN, we don't use VPN, we use VM.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio, I will check that, however like I updated my post, I am able to uploading using azure cli, not sure cors settings would impact anything.

Comment: cors only affects front -end. there's no cors issue for backend (azure function)

Comment: Hi @SolowDeveloper, could you please share your function code ? And could you please write another simple function which just upload file to blob storage but not download from sftp and then upload, test if if can upload success. You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container) to write this simple function code.

Comment: Thiago @HuryShen, I have updated the post. I followed tutorial which is working without issues. I have also added code snippet to download the blob which is throwing same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I found the solution.

I found [this article](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-with-azure-storage-and-managed-service-identity) which clearly stated in the note that Data Reader or Data Contributor role is a must! None of the MS documents such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage) did not highlight the importance of additional role (Data Reader/Data Contributor) like the article did.

> Note that it is **not enough** that your user is an Owner/Contributor on
>   the subscription/resource group/Storage account. The user must be
>   assigned to a Data Reader or Data Contributor role to get access to
>   the data using Azure AD authentication.

We assumed contributor was enough but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** 
I see your returning a `Task` from your method, yet not `await`ing anything.
Its a good practice to add the 'async` keyword to the method signature and change the following code:

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/",tenantId);
```

to something like:

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var token = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/",tenantId);
var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(token );
```

Now, get your access token your can use a tool like http://jwt.io and crack it open and inspect the claims.

**2)**
Trying changing the access token from:

```
GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/",tenantId);
```

to:

```
GetAccessTokenAsync("https://[youraccount].blob.core.windows.net",tenantId);
```

**3)**
The `AzureServiceTokenProvider` will look for credentials in a set of predefined places.

The [AzureServiceTokenProvider documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication) is worth reading through, to help trouble shoot.
Have you tried using the first option of passing `RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli` as the connection string, so it explicitly knows where to look?

So, from the same command window where you executed the azure cli and did something like `azure login`, have you tried to run the console program from there?

Which subscription are you logged into?  `az account list`
Do you have many subscriptions?
Your default subscription may not be the one where you are trying to access the blob from.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I don't have much liberty to change the code (but I will give try) because that's already deployed and running in production. Its just something I need to setup locally for running. I run az login to make sure I logged in and also az account list shwoing correct subscription (only subscription).  I am trying to set the connection string that you recommended, trying to figureout how to set it.

Comment: I have set envrionment using this command `setx AzureServicesAuthConnectionString "RunAs=App;AppId=xxxx-xxxx;TenantId=xxxxx;AppKey=xxxxxx"` Now I get a different error which is big relief for me. Error: "No matching token was found in the cacheed" looking in this direction now

Comment: No worries, you can at least make the changes in 1), so that you are properly using the TPL correctly. It won't brake any public signatures.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, the Data Reader/Contributor role must be on the storage account resource itself... it won't work at the Subscription resource level.

This feels like a bug honestly.
A user/service principle with Owner or Contributor role at the Subscription level should be allowed to upload via the cli without the supplementary role.
If I can do it from the UI, I should be able to do it via the cli too.