# "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format" from within azure portal

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-account

I have the following problem and cannot figure out where the problem is.
I created a StorageV2 (general purpose v2) storage account a few days ago, created two blob containers and two queues in it. Then uploaded some data into the blobs and the queues and stoppt working with it.
Now (the last three days), when I try to access the blob storage or the queues I receive the following error messages:

- The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format
- This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

Details see below screenshot:

[image: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.]
The problem is, I access the account via azure portal, not via code, so the same way I created the storage account. So even with the exact same user.

Update: I tested with Edge and Firefox, both same errors. Funny thing is that I can access the queues and the blobs with the Azure Storage Explorer App.

Does anyone have any advice for me?

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784133/unable-to-upload-download-blob-storage-to-container-from-local-environment/60493059#60493059.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days the problem disappeared by itself. I therefore assume that the cause lay with Microsoft. Thanks to all for the tips.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30500229)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want do do that on portal, please follow these steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you dont use portal, you can use SAS token.

Comment: Hi BowmanZhu, thank you for your sugestions. Unfortunately it does not work. Still the same errors. As I have described it should not be a problem of the user, as i created the queues and blobs with the same user with which I'm trying to access the data.